# Matplotlib- return arrays must be of ArrayType

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as  np

labels = ['2009-2015', '2016-2018', '2019-2021']
European = [92.55, 83.57, 82.52]
Asian = [5.96, 8.55, 10.68]
African = [1.49, 1.89, 6.37]
Other = [0, 5.99, 0.43]

b_African = list(np.add(European,Asian))
b_Other = list(np.add(European,Asian,African))

width = 0.35

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(labels, European, width, label='European')
ax.bar(labels, Asian, width, bottom=European,label='Asian')
ax.bar(labels, African, width, bottom=b_African,label='African')
ax.bar(labels, Other, width, bottom=b_African,label='Other')
```

---

I've got a syntax

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5cfdb21f17d8> in <module>
     10 
     11 b_African = list(np.add(European,Asian))
---> 12 b_Other = list(np.add(European, Asian,African))
     13 
     14 width = 0.35

TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

---

Do anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Adding two arrays of the same form is np.add(), so I think it is possible with the following.　`b_Other = list(np.add(np.add(European,Asian),African))`

Answer (score 0):

This answer follows the suggestion from comments.
You want to add arrays of the same type!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as  np

labels = ['2009-2015', '2016-2018', '2019-2021']
European = [92.55, 83.57, 82.52]
Asian = [5.96, 8.55, 10.68]
African = [1.49, 1.89, 6.37]
Other = [0, 5.99, 0.43]

b_African = list(np.add(European,Asian))
# This is the trick:
b_Other = list(np.add(np.add(European,Asian),African))

width = 0.35

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(labels, European, width, label='European');
ax.bar(labels, Asian, width, bottom=European,label='Asian');
ax.bar(labels, African, width, bottom=b_African,label='African');
ax.bar(labels, Other, width, bottom=b_African,label='Other');

plt.show()
```

[image]